# Replace a single element of a tuple within a list of tuples in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indexing, tuples

I have a dictionary that acts as a student database. Each key is a student name, and the value for each key is a list of tuples consisting of the course name and the grade. A student can have many courses.

Issue 1: I am aware that tuples are immutable, so I need a workaround to replace the grade value for a specific course.

Issue 2: Students can re-take a course, and if the grade is higher than their initial try, then the grade would be updated. If it is lower, the grade is not updated. Courses with a grade of 0 are not included.

I cannot seem to exclude the addition of an already-existing course with the lower grade. I keep getting duplicates of the "Introduction to Programming" course with the lower grade "2" being added.

I've been staring at this for almost a day now, any help would be greatly appreciated. And I'm sorry if this was painful to read and interpret. I'm fairly new to programming.

```py
def add_student(students: dict, name: str): 
    if len(students) == 0:
        students[name] = [()]

    if name not in students:
        students[name] = [()]
    return students

def print_student(students: dict, name: str):
    if name not in students:
        print(f"{name}: no such person in the database")
    elif students[name] == [()]:
        print(f"{name}:\n no completed courses")
        
    else:
        print(f"{name}:\n {len(students[name])} completed courses:")
        for i in range(len(students[name])):
            print(f"  {students[name][i][0]} {students[name][i][1]}")
        
        sum_course = 0
        for i in range(len(students[name])):    
            sum_course += students[name][i][1]
        print(f" average grade: {sum_course / len(students[name])}")
    return

def add_course(students: dict, name: str, course: tuple):
    if name not in students:
        print(f"{name}: no such person in the database")
        
    elif students[name] == [()] and course[1] != 0:
        students[name].append(course)
        students[name].remove(())
    
    elif course[0] not in students and course[1] !=0:
        students[name].append(course)
    
    return students
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    students = {}
    add_student(students, "Peter")
    print()
    
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 3))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Advanced Course in Programming", 2))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Data Structures and Algorithms", 0))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 2))
    print()

    print(students)
    print()
    print_student(students, "Peter")
```

Comment: You can either replace a tuple with a new one, or use a list instead, and convert the list to a tuple once the values are finalized for output.

Comment: Why not make it a `dict` with values that are `dict`s with `str` keys (the course name) and numeric values (the grade)? Makes it *dramatically* simpler and faster to find a particular course and its grade, as well as perform the replacement. And they're easy to convert to a sequence of `(key, value)` `tuple`s (with the `.items()` method).

Comment: As a side-note: `for i in range(len(x)):` is an antipattern from C programmers that won't learn better ways of doing things. Something like `for i in range(len(students[name])): print(f"  {students[name][i][0]} {students[name][i][1]}")` can be expressed *much* more Pythonically, and significantly more efficiently, as `for course, grade in students[name]: print(f"  {course} {grade}")`. If you followed my suggestion to use `dict`s instead of `list`s of two-`tuple`s, that would just change `students[name]` to `students[name].items()` and otherwise remain the same.

Comment: @ShadowRanger this is terrific, thank you. 

The exercise starts by saying ".. and thinking about what sort of data structures are necessary for organizing the data stored by your program." I should have taken that note more seriously! thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I took the recommendations from @ShadowRanger and put them into a full answer, with code and plenty of comments to explain what's happening.

Here are the high level notes

- You can change students to be `dict` with keys of student names and values of `dict`s with keys of course names and values of grades. This makes it much easier to access, update, etc
- Because we are not using errors to indicate what happens in the function, you can use the return values in `add_student`, `add_course` and `print_student` to indicate if any operation was performed

  - You don't need to return the `dict` again since it was altered in place by the function
- You can restructure `add_student` to be a little clearer - checking if an iterable is empty then checking if an item is in that iterable is redundant, python gracefully handles `in` calls against empty iterables
- You can have the return from `add_course` to work same as `add_student`
- You can restructure print student a little to reflect the benefits of the new data structure
- You can indicate the types within the tuple on the `add_course` as that function is quite strict

Here is some code demonstrating those suggestions:

```
def add_student(students: dict, name: str) -> bool:
    # If this student is already in the students, no operation
    #   return False to indicate no changes
    if name in students:
        return False
    # If this is a new student, put in a dict for them
    #   return True to indicate a change
    students[name] = {}
    return True


def add_course(students: dict, name: str, course: tuple[str, int]) -> bool:
    # If the student isn't in students, print the warning and
    #   return False to indicate no changes
    if name not in students:
        print(f'{name}: no such person in the database')
        # We could optionally instead throw an error here and
        #   let the calling function handle it
        return False
    # If the student got a 0, ignore the request and
    #   return False to indicate no changes
    if course[1] == 0:
        # We don't include courses with 0 grade
        return False
    # If this is the first time they took the course, add it and
    #   return True to indicate an update
    if course[0] not in students[name]:
        students[name][course[0]] = course[1]
        return True
    # If the student took it before and did better this time, update it and
    #   return True to indicate an update
    if course[1] > students[name][course[0]]:
        students[name][course[0]] = course[1]
        return True
    # If the student took it before and id better then, leave it and
    #   return False to indicate no changes
    return False


def print_student(students: dict, name: str) -> bool:
    # If the student isn't in students, print the warning and
    #   return False to indicate the student print failed
    if name not in students:
        print(f'{name}: no such person in the database')
        # We could optionally instead throw an error here and
        #   let the calling function handle it
        return False
    # Print the student name and course count
    print(f'{name}:')
    # Print the number of completed courses
    #   If only 1 has been completed, no 's' should be added to 'course'
    #   i.e., no courses, 1 course, 2 courses, 3 courses, etc
    print(f' {len(students[name]) or "no"} completed course' +
        ('' if len(students[name]) == 1 else 's')
    )
    # This loop will print each course, if there are any
    for course, grade in students[name].items():
        print(f'  {course} {grade}')
    # This will print the average grade if the student has taken 1 or more
    if len(students[name]):
        print(f' average grade: {sum(students[name].values()) / len(students[name])}')
    # return True to indicate the student print succeeded
    return True


if __name__ == "__main__":
    students = {}
    add_student(students, "Peter")
    add_student(students, "Sally")
    print()

    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 3))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Advanced Course in Programming", 2))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Data Structures and Algorithms", 0))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to Programming", 2))
    print()

    print(students)
    print()
    print_student(students, "Peter")
    print_student(students, "Sally")
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @ShadowRanger's suggestion. We should make each student record a dictionary `{course_name: grade}`. Then, the students database would look something like this:

```json
{
    "Peter": {
        "Introduction to Programming": 3,
        "Advanced Course in Programming": 2
    }
}
```

This will make it easier to update. Here is my code:

```py
import statistics

def add_course(students: dict, name: str, course_name: str, grade: int):
    student = students.setdefault(name, {})
    existing_grade = student.get(course_name, 0)
    grade = max(grade, existing_grade)
    if grade == 0:
        return
    student[course_name] = grade
    
def print_student(students: dict, name: str):
    student = students.get(name)

    if student is None:
        print(f"{name}: no such person in the database")
        return
    
    if not student:
        print(f"{name}:\n no completed courses")
        return

    gpa = statistics.mean(student.values())
    print(f"{name}:")
    print(f"  Number of completed courses: {len(student)}")
    print(f"  Grade Point Average: {gpa}")
    print("  Courses and Grades:")
          
    for course_name, grade in student.items():
        print(f"   - {course_name}: {grade}")
```

In the main code:

```py
students = {}
add_course(students, "Peter", "Introduction to Programming", 3)
add_course(students, "Peter", "Advanced Course in Programming", 2)
add_course(students, "Peter", "Data Structures and Algorithms", 0)
add_course(students, "Peter", "Introduction to Programming", 2)
print_student(students, "Peter")
```

Output:

```
Peter:
  Number of completed courses: 2
  Grade Point Average: 2.5
  Courses and Grades:
   - Introduction to Programming: 3
   - Advanced Course in Programming: 2
```

Notes

- I don't have `add_student`: the student name will be added automatically in `add_course`
- When dealing with a dictionary, learn to use the methods such as `.get()`, and `.setdefault()`, they will greatly simplify your code.