# Update dictionary only when new entry is bigger than previous one

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to create a student database, where courses (in the format of a tuple (Course name: int, grade: int) are added to a dictionary (students: dict). However, if the student already completed the course (there is already a course with same name in database), this should only replace the previous value, if the new grade is bigger than old one.

I have tried several things, but am struggling to make sure only grades that were greater update the dictionary

```
def add_course(students: dict,   name_student: str, course_info: tuple[str, float]):
    course_name = course_info[0]
    grade = course_info[1]
    courses = students[name_student ]

    if name_student in students.keys(): 
        if courses == "no completed courses": #check whether has any entry
            students[name_student] = [course_info]
            return
        else: #= student is in database and has other entries 
            for i in range(len(courses)):
                if courses[i][0] == course_name: #if there is course name with other 
                    if int(courses[i][1]) < int(grade):
                        courses[i][1] = grade
                        students[name_student] = courses
                        break
                    else: #if grade is smaller, do nothing 
                        break
             #if no course with same name
                elif course_name not in courses[i][0]:
                    print("courses", courses)
                    print("course name", course_name)
                    courses.append((course_name, grade))
                    students[name_student] = courses
                  print("students[name_student]",students[name_student])
                    return
    else:
        return "Student not in the database"


    #output
    # print(f"{name_student}:")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    students = {"Peter": "no completed courses"}
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Introduction to 
Programming", 5))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Advanced Programming", 7))
    add_course(students, "Peter", ("Advanced Programming", 5))
    print_student(students, "Peter")
```

Comment: Check the dictionary to see if it already contains a bigger value for that course.  If it does, don't update it.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: How do you know your code isn't working? Be precise, [edit] the question.

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77651499/459745

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure makes the logic more complicated than is needs to be.  Ideally, your list of courses and grades for a student should actually be a dictionary with the course names as key.  Also, the absence of completed courses should be represented by an empty list or dictionary rather than a string (which makes the content type irregular and requires additional conditions in your logic).

Without changing the data structure, the function could temporarily convert the list of courses to a dictionary, update the grade and turn it back into a list for the student:

```
def add_course(students: dict,   name_student: str, course_info: tuple[str, float]):
    if name_student not in students:
        return "Student not in the database"
    course, newGrade = course_info
    courses          = students[name_student]
    grades           = dict()
    if courses != "no completed courses":
        grades.update(courses)
    grades[course]   = max(grades.get(course,newGrade),newGrade)
    students[name_student] =  list(grades.items())
```

With a more appropriate data structure (i.e. values of students are {course:grade} dictionaries, empty when no courses completed), the function would be more straightforward:

```
def add_course(students: dict,   name_student: str, course_info: tuple[str, float]):
    if name_student not in students:
        return "Student not in the database"
    course, newGrade = course_info
    grades           = students[name_student]
    grades[course]   = max(grades.get(course,newGrade),newGrade)
```